# Additional security checks on Symfony login

Tags: php, validation, symfony, authentication

I'm using symfony 2.5 and I've come across a roadblock.

I am using `SecurityContext` as per symfony documentation in order to authenticate users.  Specifically I currently have:

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');

# If authenticated through Symfony
if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'))
{
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('accounts_dashboard'), 301);

}
.....
```

This works well but this application registers users from several locations and at the time we didn't control duplicate registrations.  This means we have multiple entries for the same email address.

Because of this, when someone tries to login and there are several accounts under the same email address the login procedure fails because it is selecting the wrong account.

I have other fields in the database that I could use to match the correct accounts, like active status, last login IP or even the last login date.  The issue I have is that I am uncertain how to create additional checks during login to validate that information properly.

What would be the correct approach without having to rework the entire login logistics so that I could do additional checks on the database for the provided email address before calling `SecurityContext` and the rest of the login procedure?  Essentially I am just trying to do additional checks after the login for has been submitted to ensure the correct account is being selected instead of the first match in the database.

Comment: i should clean up that usertable before i should go any futher. write a script that compares the emails and save only the one with the last logindate into a new usertable

Comment: @Frankbeen what you are suggesting sounds like trying to cleanup a mess by creating a new mess (a second user table).  Long term this app will avoid creating duplicate accounts in the first place but that is ahead of me.  The immediate requirement is being able to deal with existing duplicate accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom UserProvider. Example:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Security\Authorization;


use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;

class MyCustomEmailUserProvider extends EntityUserProvider
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {

        //your code to get user by email goes here
        // if you found User, you need to return it from this method, otherwise throw an exception

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User "%s" not found.', $username));
    }
}
```

You don't have to extend `EntityUserProvider`, you may consider your own `UserProviderInterface` implementation.

Register it as a service (assuming `security.my_custom_email_user_provider` service name), add your required dependencies and then add it to `security.yml`:

```
providers:
    main:
        id: security.my_custom_email_user_provider
```

And then use this provider on your login form:

```
firewalls:
      firewall_name:
            form_login:
                 provider: main
```

Check out [Cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) for additional information.

Comment: Thank you.  I can make perfect sense of the logic here but I am having difficulties to implement.  I created a bundle\Security\User\CustomUserProvider.php class with your example and named the class CustomUserProvider.  I then added the service as:     `providers:
        main:
                class: bundle\Security\User\CustomUserProvider` but the customuserprovider class does not seem to be doing anything.  To test I attempted to return an invalid user and it still logged me in.  So my best guess is that the service registration is not taking place correctly?

Comment: I have to apologize, that didn't make much sense.  What I mean to say is that I created a service like: `security.my_custom_email_user_provider` under my config file for services, I then added that registered service under `security.yml` using its ID, but none of it seems to be having any effect on the website as I am still able to login normally without issues when I shouldn't considering I am forcing return of an invalid username in the customuserprovider class.

Comment: @JoseRLopezmomon Right, I forgot the part where you need to add it to your login form, updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the follow up.  I had tried that before and had the same results.  Let me attempt to redo the whole thing again and see if it works now.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry.  I've tried everything I can think off and the custom user provider does not seem to be having any sort of impact.  I've done everything as suggested and even attempted again from scratch following the documentation to the letter.  No matter what I do the custom user provider class is never called during login.

Comment: @JoseRLopezmomon I don't know what's happening there, you can probably ask a new question at this point, providing details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am now getting somewhere.  It was cache that was messing with me all along.  I now get an error which reads as follows: `Fatal error: Class My\Bundle\Security\User\CustomUserProvider contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface::refreshUser, Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface::supportsClass) in /home/***/src/My/Bundle/Security/User/CustomUserProvider.php on line 28` ... I could implement the classes but I am not 100% sure what they should return.

Comment: Apologies, the error I pasted before is from when I was trying to guide on the cookbook.  Here is the error I get from your example implementation above: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, none given, called in /home/***/app/cache/pro_/ap_ProdProjectContainer.php on line 265 and defined in /home/**/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php on line 35`

Comment: Ok, I'm now very close.  I am now able to see the custom user provider being used.  I had success following this guide in conjunction with your example: http://clintberry.com/2011/custom-user-providers-symfony2/.  The issue I still have now is that I do not seem to have access to the $username variable on that function, for some reason it appears to be empty.  I can see the function working but the variable is always empty and thus I'm unable to implement the necessary logic on it.  I can see the original provider does specify property: email, how do I implement this for the custom provider?

Answer (score 0):

UserProvider should return user by username, nothing else, it should not do some heavy logic. I think you can try to create your own authenticator as explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html) by implementing the `SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface` interface.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but as I explained in my original post I can't afford to refactor the entire app and reworking the authentication right now will force me to do that because of the way the app was built, so I am currently looking for a simple way to tell symfony which is the correct username / email to be used for authentication purposes rather than letting it find the first entry from the database.

Comment: @JoseRLopezmomon You don't have to refactor the project, just add the authenticator class, register it as a service, add it to the existing firewall, flush the caches, that's it.

Comment: I appreciate the follow up but unfortunately as I said before I can't refactor the whole thing.  I didn't build this and it wasn't built using standards strictly.  There is a lot of customization that relies in the way the login works, so tampering with that in favor for a new authentication is likely to break things so I rather go for a simpler solution like simply adjusting the userprovider class to fit my needs.  I got a good idea how to achieve that from another reply now I am just trying to make it work under my setup.